# How to show a string 10 times using while loop in assembly language?

Tags: loops, assembly, while-loop

**how to show string 10 times in assembly language?**

*Here is my code*

```
.model small
 .stack 100h
 .data
    msg db 'rashed   $'
 .code

 main proc


    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    lea dx,msg
    mov ah,9      ;string output
     int 21h 


      mov dx,0   ;dx counts characters
      mov ah,9   ;prepare for read
      int 21h  





     while_:
      cmp al,0dh     ;carriage return?
      je end_while    ;yes exit
      inc dx           ;not carrage return,increament count
      int 21h          ;read character
      jmp while_       ;loop back
      end_while:  
    exit:
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
    main endp
 end main
```

**output is:**

[image]

**i want to show this string   10 times but the string subtracts??
how to show that 10 times??**

Comment: can you add comments into your code, why did you write those instructions, and what do you think they are doing? (how to show it 10 times: just call DOS service to display string 10 times with correct arguments)

Comment: int 21h/ah=9 doesn't read, it writes a `$` terminated string pointed to by DS:DX

Comment: @ Michael Petc
tnx Thats my little mistake
but help me to get that string in 10 times 
thank you

Comment: It's not **little** mistake, almost all comments and the instructions don't match. Not even enough to just give you some hints and fix 1-2 things, that code is doing something completely different. Try to fix all comments to describe what the code is doing, use google to see what `int 21h` DOS services do, and use Intel instruction reference guide to see what particular instruction does. Read some Assembly tutorial/book. (the only somewhat correct comment is the first *";string output"*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> mov dx,0   ;dx counts characters
> ```

To show the same text a number of times, choose a counter register different from the registers that are required to perform the output (In your case `AX` and `DX`). I suggest putting the counter in `CX`.

```
    mov  cx, 11
while_:
    dec  cx           ;Change counter
    jz   end_while    ;Exit after 10 iterations
    mov  ah, 9
    int  21h          ;Print string
    jmp while_        ;Loop back
end_while:
```

Because a **while-loop**  tests the condition first, I assigned **11**
instead of 10.